# How to setup ping between XP guest from Win8 Host using Hyper-V virtual swtich

Tags: hyper-v, windows-8, windows-xp

Hyper-V client is installed on a Win8 Pro 64 bit box and a VM running XP has been created within that with an internal virtual swtich.

The VM can be booted and accessed and there is a default virtual NIC within it with dynamic IP  of 169.254.x.x which i have changed to be a static IP of 192.168.0.12/255.255.255.0 confirmed via ipconfig on the XP guest.

The Host has IP of 192.168.0.7/255.255.255.0. Both host and guest have their firewalls disabled for simplicity.

I cant ping guest from host nor host from guest. TTL timeout. And with regard to Hyper-V and VMs I dont know what to do next. Both are in same workgroup (as per name) but since they cant ping I guess that means nothing.

....

My objective is to share a folder on VM so I can install a 32bit accountancy app that wont run on Win8/7 so if there is a more simplistic way then Im all ears but typically a peer to peer is very simple.

Comment: So a simple work around is too create an ISO and load that into the VM DVD drive via the Menu Bar..... dont want to have to do this all the time tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i rebooted 3 times and that seems to have solved it. Have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the following :
- in the Virtual Network Manager GUI, is your virtual network type "**Internal only**" or "**External**" ? the "**Private**" one doesn't allow guest to contact host.
- did you ping the IP or DNS name ? none of them work ?

On Windows 7/8, you've to check in the "Network and Sharing Center" > "Change advanced sharing setting" that the :

**file and printer sharing** is on

**password protected sharing** is off

**network discovery** is on

Should be enough

Comment: internal, on, off, on. no joy.

Comment: I turned on everything, but I think network discovery is what fixed my problem.